# Find how many quadruples given upper limits for each number where xor result is zero

Tags: python, combinatorics, xor

A,B,C,D,W,X,Y, and Z are all positive integers where given A,B,C,D:

```
1<=W<=A
1<=X<=B
1<=Y<=C
1<=Z<=D
```

How many quadruples (W,X,Y,Z) where W XOR X XOR Y XOR Z = 0? Order does not matter, meaning (2,2,3,3) is the same as (2,3,2,3).

I originally thought only quadruples like (n,n,n,n) and (n1,n1,n2,n2) would XOR to 0, but it turns out that something like (1,2,4,7) can all XOR to 0 too. I'm now not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Surely you can code at least a brute force solution?

Comment: So, you're not given A, B, C, and D?  You're supposed to concoct a formula that depends on A, B, C, and D?  That's tricky.  Empirically, it looks like about 3%, but I don't know how you'd express that mathematically.  You'd need the number of combos where the number of 1 bits in each position is even.

Comment: Do you have any information about any of A, B, C, or D? In particular, do you know either that the largest is of the form 2^k-1, or that the largest has a higher set bit than the 2nd largest?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a <= b <= c <= d. We can always relabel variables to make this true.

For every combination of w, x, and y, the only value of z that will cause XOR(w, x, y, z) = 0 is z = XOR(w, x, y).

This gives us an upper limit on our count of quadruples of a * b * c, but it will need to be reduced because of two factors:

- Here order matters, but the OP doesn't want to count permutations of solutions: (2,2,3,3) is the same as (2,3,2,3).
- in some cases, XOR(w, x, y) > d, so this will count some invalid solutions.

If d is of the form 2^k - 1, or if d has a larger max set bit than c, then there can be no invalid solutions.

We can assume w <= x <= y <= z.

A possible but slow way of solving this in O(a*b*c) is:

```
def f(a, b, c, d)
  # this assumes a <= b <= c <= d
  count = 0
  1.upto(a) do |w|
    w.upto(b) do |x|
      x.upto(c) do |y|
        z = w ^ x ^ y
        if y <= z && z <= d
          count += 1
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return count
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Preparing data:

```
A, B, C, D =  (1,2,4,7)
```

Brute Force using if for filtering true:

```
comb = [(W, X, Y, Z) for W in range(1, A + 1) for X in range(1, B + 1) for Y in range(1, C + 1) for Z in range(1, D + 1) if (W != X) != (Y != Z)]
```

The answer is the length of comb:

```
len(comb)
```

Output: 28